# Is Truffle migrate compiling my code over and over again?

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Each time I run the `truffle migrate` command, I see the following messages:

```
Compiling .\contracts\DateTime.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\DateTimeUtils.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\ERC20Token.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\SafeMath.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\StringLib.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\getPrice.sol...
Compiling .\contracts\oraclizeAPI_0.4.sol...
```

Is `truffle migrate` compiling all my source files again, despite there being no changes? Or is truffle just showing which files it's checking?

If not, what is it doing when it shows "Compiling *sourcefilename*" when doing a migration?

How can I fix this, if it's really compiling?

I'm using Truffle v4.0.0-beta.0 (core: 4.0.0-beta.0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it seems like truffle is compiling all your source code again. Assuming you aren't making any changes to the code, this seems like a bug. Clearly you are using a early-beta version of truffle 4, so this might be the case.

In the current version of truffle (truffle 3.4.11 I believe), truffle migrate will only recompile contracts that have changed since the last compilation.

EDIT: Ah, after upgrading some of my contracts to solidity version 0.4.15, I am getting this same issue with truffle 3.4.11. I haven't found a work around, nor a --no-compile option to use.

From their documentation:

```
Truffle will compile only the contracts that have been changed since the last compile, to reduce any unnecessarily compilation.
```